# How to count inner tags during parsing XML with XmlPullParser

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing, xmlpullparser, android-xmlpullparser

I'm parsing layout file with `XmlPullParser` and I need to count inner tags to be able recognize children views. I found the method to count attributes for each tag, but cannot find how to count exactly tags.

I have code like this one:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#0d3fff"
            android:text="New Button 1"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/btnDef1"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btnDef2"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/tv1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Anyone has ideas how to count children for tag `LinearLayout`?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no Idea why anyone would want to count tags from a Layout file. If you are inflating the layout use either the getChildCount method or use the following code to get count of child of LinearLayout

```
int childcount = ll.getChildCount();
for (int i=0; i < childcount; i++){
    View v = ll.getChildAt(i);
}
```

If you are inclined on using XMLPullparser, I dont think there is any direct method to count xml Tags. You have to go through each tag

```
    int count = 0;
    XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();
    try {
        xpp.setInput(new InputStreamReader(is));

        int eventType = xpp.next();
        Project p = null;
        while(eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
             count++;
             String tagName = xpp.getName();
             switch (eventType) {
                 case XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT:
                    break;
                // and other cases that you want to handle
             }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I see I explained not enough... I need to count tags !before! parser goes through all of them. I need after root tag start loop and need to count children when to stop it. I cannot inflate it, because I need to modify it and it is not in res folder

Comment: In case of XML, you have to go step by step untill you find a END_DOCUMENT. That is the problem with xml. You can use JSON, this is a lot flexible. You can make key value pairs and put the value as those xml tags, though I would not recommend this. Bad practice/design/usage.

Comment: yeah, JSON much more flexible, I agree, maybe I'll look in that side. But setting new layout in runtime maybe not the best practice yeah, but still very useful in my case. Anyways, thank you for your response.